# How to play Spotify links using lavaplayer?

Tags: java, discord, lavaplayer

The Github page for Lavaplayer says that it can use OGG audio files, which is what spotify links use to store audio. if you provide lavaplayer with a spotify link (either a song link or a embed code) then it can't find an audio file, is there a way to make the audioplayer understand spotify links?

Answer (score 0):

You can't play spotify tracks with Lavaplayer you need to use the Spotify API to get the track name then search youtube for that track name and play that instead. Almost all legal ~ish bots use this as spotify doesn't allow anyone other than their users to play tracks.